# Why does C# implicitly convert to nullable DateTime if there is no implicit operator for nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#

This is a question about the C# language or at least how that language is implemented in Visual Studio.

Assume one has a class Foo which defines an implicit operator to System.DateTime

```
public static implicit operator DateTime(Foo item)
```

Consider the following code:

```
Foo foo = SomeMethodWhichCanReturnNull();    
DateTime?  dtFoo = foo;
```

**What I would expect:**
A failure-to-compile complaining that there is no conversion from `Foo` to `DateTime?`.

**What I find:** The compiler actually calls the defined implicit operator from `Foo` to `DateTime` and crashes when it is passed a null (which is the only way the converter can respond to a null).

Of course, work-around is to define

```
public static implicit operator DateTime?(Foo item)
```

but why do I have to do this?  Are not `DateTime` and `DateTime?` two different types?

Comment: I'm not seeing an exception with a simple implementation. What does your implicit operator do when passed a null?

Comment: @mikez it (his conversion method) throws an exception. That's the core problem here.

Comment: @TimS. So the issue is then in the implementation of the implicit conversion, not the compiler causing a null reference exception because of it inserting a lifting conversion from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`.

Comment: @mikez Yep, I do believe that's the problem.

Comment: No, the issue is that I was not expecting this converter to be called for converting to DateTime?.   If it did not throw an exception, it would have to return *some* DateTime value (any choice of which would be bogus and probably cause other errors).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, the C# language specification says that a built-in implicit conversion can be inserted on *either side* of a user-defined implicit conversion. So if you had a user-defined implicit conversion from `Shape` to `Giraffe` then you are automatically allowed to convert from `Square` to `Mammal`, because it goes `Square --> Shape --> Giraffe --> Mammal`.  In your case the extra conversion is only inserted on one side, presuming that the operand is of type `Foo`. There is an implicit conversion from any type to its corresponding nullable type. A second *user defined* conversion is never inserted; only *built in* conversions can be inserted on either side.

(I note that this is true of user-defined *explicit* conversions as well; *explicit* conversions may be inserted on either side.)

Second, you are in violation of the specification, which strongly suggests that a user-defined implicit conversion should never throw an exception. If you cannot guarantee that the operation will succeed then either change the types or make it an explicit conversion.

Third, you might be interested to know that the C# compiler will automatically define a "lifted" conversion if both types in a user-defined implicit conversion are non-nullable value types. If you have a user-defined implicit conversion from struct type S to struct type T then you get a "lifted" conversion from S? to T? for free, with the semantics of `s.HasValue ? new T?((T)s.Value) : new T?()`.

This subject is one of the more complex areas in the C# specification so I recommend that you read it carefully if you wish to know the exact details.

Comment: The key fact you brought out was **"There is an implicit conversion from any type to its corresponding nullable type."**

Comment: @Tevya: If the semantics of nullable operations interest you, consider reading my lengthy series: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Answer (score 7):

`DateTime?` is actually a C# syntactic sugar to represent `Nullable<DateTime>`. When you write something like `DateTime?  dtFoo = foo` the compiler actually generate code like:

```
Nullable<DateTime> dtFoo = new Nullable<DateTime>(foo);
```

Which is perfectly fine from compiler point of view as the nullable constructor take a `DateTime` as param and `foo` has type conversion for it.

Comment: +1 for `Nullable`, I wonder if it's a good practice to use Nullable variables, though.. as allowing null is like allowing 2 distinct types of data in the same container

Comment: @Frederik.L: How is a nullable `DateTime` different from a nullable `string`?

Comment: @EricLippert `string` is a *reference type*, while `DateTime` is a *value type*, which means that `null` makes no sense unless some wizardry is done

Comment: @Frederik.L: But *why*?  Why should it be the case that *whether a value is indirected through a reference or not* affects whether the type can be *nullable*? You can make a method that takes a `ref int` which is implemented as a reference to a variable, but that reference cannot be null, so nullability and reference passing could be orthogonal. My point is that your claim "allowing null is like allowing two distinct types in the same container" applies equally well to string as it does to int?, so shouldn't we then by your logic avoid `string`?

Comment: @EricLippert An integer cannot exist in memory without having a numeric value. A null reference imply that nothing is referenced. Therefore, a null reference to an integer is not likely to happen. From my understanding of internal memory, every types that can be quantified in space are more likely to be *value type* (not nullable), while types that cannot are more likely to be *reference type* (nullable) so there could be a pointer that points toward a value that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: We can compare that to : In one hand, I have a potato. In the other one, I have a bag of potatoes. Although my bag can contain nothing at all, my hand that carries a potato sure has something, as it makes no sense to say it contains nothing.

Comment: In such a case, the bag is naturally nullable while the potatoe isn't.

Comment: @EricLippert No we should not avoid the nullable `string` since a string can be an Array of characters that contains nothing yet. But an integer (or a date) can hardly exist without having a certain value into it, as from the moment you allocate some memory, there is binary stuff in there. To allow the *null* value, we must add some mechanics around it.

Comment: @Frederik.L  If you don't use a nullable type, how do you represent the "no value assigned" state?

Comment: @DanNeely I do agree that it is better to use Nullable than magic numbers. However I prefer using booleans to check whether or not the value should be used to go further. ie: `if (step_for_it_to_be_assigned_is_done) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @Frederik.L a nullable type combines a flag and the value and enforces its use so you can't have a forgot-to-check-the-flag and corrupted something because the error wasn't detected bug.

Comment: @Frederik.L: Congratulations, you just re-invented nullable types! A nullable value type is *an instance of the value type attached to a bool*. Nullable value types are literally nothing more than sticking your bool next to the value that it is commenting on.

Comment: @Frederik.L: My hands contain neither potatoes nor bags; how is it nonsensical to say that they contain nothing?

Comment: @EricLippert If your hand doesn't contain a potato, why does its type should be potato? An article that supports my point on that: http://mattdavey.me/2012/02/03/null-the-most-abused-keyword-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

When you have this:

```
Foo foo = SomeMethodWhichCanReturnNull();    
DateTime? dtFoo = foo;
```

The compiler sees that there is an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `DateTime`, and an implicit conversion from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`. It decides it can thus implicitly convert from `Foo` to `DateTime?` and quite happily compiles.

An `implicit` operator [should not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throw an exception. The fact that you are violating this is why you are seeing confusing behavior. You should probably change that to an `explicit` operator, and optionally add an `implicit` conversion to `DateTime?` that returns `null` in the case of a `null` `Foo`.

Comment: Actually, he's not throwing an exception: there's a NullReferenceException thrown, as you can't convert a null reference type to a non-nullable value type.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Actually, I'm pretty sure his `implicit` method is throwing a `NullReferenceException`, because it's implemented something like: `{ return item.DateValue; }`. Since operators are static, you can get into it regardless of a null.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance That's because you shouldn't have an implicit conversion from an object to a struct, anyway.

Comment: @Yandros I wouldn't say that's strictly true: as long as you know what `struct` value should be returned when the value of the object is null, you can implicitly convert.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance True.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid for the same reason you can do the following:

```
DateTime time1 = new DateTime();
DateTime? time2 = time1;
```

A normal `DateTime` can be transformed into a `nullable DateTime`. This means that your `Foo` class, which acts like a `DateTime`, can follow the path `Foo -> DateTime -> DateTime?`

I guess `DateTime?` (or any other null-ed class) has an implicit operator to its normal type.

Comment: Not quite, it's just that Nullable<T> is very special in the eyes of the compiler.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, I agree, but where did I get this wrong?

Comment: It's not casted, it's actually constructed like this: `new Nullable<DateTime>(originalDateTime);`

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, so i'm basically right if I just say that it uses "behind the scenes magic" for the "conversion"?

Comment: What would be more interesting would be to swap the two lines:    
DateTime? xxx = new DateTime();
DateTime yyy = xxx;

According to the rules, this should pass the compiler because there is an implicit conversion from DateTime? to DateTime, right?

Comment: @Tevya, no, that would not work. You can go from not-nullable -> nullable just fine, but not the other way around. What if you set `xxx = null`? You can't make make `DateTime yyy = null`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that `T?` (when `T`'s a struct) actually means `Nullable<T>`.

Now, let's make a short test program that replicates this:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime? x = new Program();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(Program x)
    {
        return new DateTime();
    }
}
```

And now see what it compiles to (decompiled using the great dotPeek):

```
using System;
internal class Program
{
  public Program()
  {
    base..ctor();
  }

  public static implicit operator DateTime(Program x)
  {
    return new DateTime();
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DateTime? nullable = new DateTime?((DateTime) new Program()); 
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
}
```

In fact, dotPeek is being nice to me here: it should be the same, but with `DateTime? nullable = new DateTime?((DateTime) new Program());` changed into `Nullable<DateTime> nullable = new Nullable<DateTime>((DateTime) new Program());`

As you can see, `implicit` conversions are just turned into `explicit` ones by the compiler.

What I'm guessing happens is that the compiler first thinks<sup>[1]</sup> that you can't make `Foo` a `DateTime?`, as a) it's not a reference type, and b) it's not a `DateTime`. So then it might go through some of its implicit operators<sup>[2]</sup> , and finds one that matches `DateTime`. And then it realizes<sup>[1]</sup> that you can convert a `DateTime` to a `Nullable<DateTime>`, so it then does it.

:)

<sup>[1]</sup>: Not really thinks, but don't be pedantic. 
<sup>[2]</sup>: Eric Lippert has a comment about this, that explains it.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` being special has nothing to do with this. You could do the same thing with three classes or structs you create yourself.

Comment: @TimS. Sorry, what I meant to say there is that `?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<whatever>`

Comment: In other words `?` is special.

Comment: Your guess is mostly correct. Your error is in saying "all its implicit operators";  when faced with an otherwise illegal conversion from S to T, the compiler first obtains the underlying types if either is nullable. It then searches *only* those two types for implicit user-defined operators, and then performs a complex "betterness" analysis to determine which is the unique best possible operator given the source and destination types. If no such operator can be found then an error is produced.

Comment: @EricLippert So it doesn't search quite all of them?

Comment: Correct. Here's an example: suppose you have an user-defined *explicit* conversion from `Giraffe` to `Shape` defined on type `Giraffe`. If you convert an `Animal` to `Triangle` then *the conversion is not found*, even though the explicit conversion `Animal --> Giraffe --> Shape --> Triangle` would be legal if it *could* be found. The compiler in this case would search only for user-defined explicit conversions on `Animal` and `Triangle`, and would not find the one on `Giraffe`.  If the compiler searched for *all possible explicit conversions* then it would find it, but it does not.